# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre chown y chmod?

Tags: bash, linux

Me interesa conocer la diferencia de estos para saber ¿cuándo usar cuál?. En el caso que requiera modificar los permisos de un directorio o archivo en mi *localhost*.

**Nota:** He leído varios temas en español pero percibo que explican de manera banal, encuentro mejor info en inglés pero no les entiendo del todo.

Al final termino resolviéndolo con algo que considero «nacada» pero funciona:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 -R /ruta/
```

Aunque después de tiempo ya me he cansado de dicha solución y prefiero hacerlo a lo correcto.

Comment: ¿Has realizado alguna búsqueda antes de publicar la pregunta aquí? ¿Existe algo que no entiendas entre las funcionalidades de estos comandos? Sino, esta pregunta no está dentro de los parámetros del sitio.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Si, he leído varios temas en español pero percibo que explican de manera vanal, encuentro mejor info en inglés pero no les entiendo del todo.

Comment: Oh entiendo. Entonces sería bueno si editas tu pregunta e indicas lo que mencionas en tu comentario.

Comment: creo que es _diff <(man chown) <(man chmod)_

Comment: ¿Nacada == hack?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz «nacada» puede ser usada en diferentes contextos, pero al que aquí refiero es como una forma de hacer algo que quizá no es la mejor pero funciona (también puede tomarse como sinónimo de «tontería»).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`chmod` es para cambiar los permisos (de inglés **ch**ange **mod**e)

`chown` es para cambiar de dueño (del inglés **ch**ange **own**er)

Para cambiar permisos usa el primero.

Los permisos están representados por banderas que indican si el permiso está puesto o no:

`r` de lectura (**r**ead)

`w` de escritura (**w**rite)

`x` de ejecución (e**x**ecution)

Si el permiso no está puesto aparece un guión `-`

Y están agrupados en tres niveles:

- Permisos para el dueño
- Permisos para el grupo
- Permisos para el resto.

Adicionalmente la primera letra denota si es un directorio o no

Entonces un archivo que tuviera todos los permisos se vería así:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  3  tu   tugrupo 123 Dec 15 11:11 algun.archivo
```

Y uno que no tuviera ningun permiso se vería así:

```
----------  3  tu   tugrupo 123 Dec 15 11:11 algun.archivo
```

El comando **chmod** puede recibir como argumento un número que represente cada grupo de permisos por ejemplo

```
chmod 777 archivo
```

Le da todos los permisos al archivo

Cada grupo de permisos se puede pensar como si fuera un número binario.

Por ejemplo ningún permiso sería el 0

```
0 = --- ( como el 000 binario )
```

solo de ejecución sería 1

```
1 = --x ( como el 001 binario)
```

solo escritura, 2

```
2 = -w- ( como el 010 binario )
```

escritura y ejecución, 3

```
3 = -wx ( como el 011 binario )
```

solo lectura, 4

```
4 = r-- (como el 100 binario)
```

lectura y ejecución, 5

```
5 = r-x (como el 101 binario)
```

lectura y escritura, 6

```
6 = rw- (como el 110 binario)
```

Todos los permisos, 7

```
7 = rwx ( como el 111 binario )
```

Otro ejemplo: todos los permisos para el dueño (`7=rwx`) lectura y ejecución para el grupo (`5=r-x`)  y de solo lectura para el resto (`4=r--`) se especificará así:

```
 chmod 754 archivo
```

También es posible poner y quitar permisos específicos usando el formato:

```
quien +/- permiso
```

Donde quien es `u` para el dueño( user ) o `g` para el grupo y `o` para el resto (otros)

Entonces si se quisiera quitar el permiso de escritura para otros se puede escribir:

```
chmod o-w archivo
```

yo lo leo como: *chmod otros menos write archivo*

O para agregar el permiso de ejecución al dueño

```
chmod u+x archivo
```

*chmod user más execute archivo*

Si no se especifica el "quien"  el agregar o quitar aplica para los tres grupos, así para que todos puedan leer  sería

```
chmod +r archivo
```

Comment: 3 es 011 en binario, entonces ejecución y escritura, y solo lectura es 4 (100), ¿no?

Comment: Tienes razón @PeterOlson corregido, como ya tenía 4 ejemplos puse los tres restantes completando la tabla

Answer (score 5):

Change mode (`chmod`), cambia los permisos de acceso (lectura, escritura y ejecución. `r`, `w` y `x` respectivamente):

```
$ touch archivo
$ ls -la archivo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar    0 dic 16 14:53 archivo
$ chmod a+x archivo
$ ls -la archivo 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cesar cesar 0 dic 16 14:53 archivo
```

En el ejemplo anterior la agregué permisos de ejecución (`x`) a todos (usuario, grupo y otros) usando `a`

---

Change owner (`chown`) cambio a los propietarios (usuarios, grupos):

```
$ touch archivo
$ ls -la archivo 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cesar cesar 0 dic 16 14:55 archivo
$ chown juan:juan archivo
$ ls -la archivo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 juan juan 0 dic 16 14:55 archivo
```

En el ejemplo anterior la cambie el `user:group` al archivo de `cesar:cesar` a `juan:juan`

Answer (score 4):

El comando **chown** sirve para cambiar el propietario de un archivoo fichero y la información del grupo de usuario, el comando **chmod** sirve para cambiar los permisos de acceso al archivo tales como escritura, lectura y ejecución.

Por ejemplo:

```
chown usuario:grupo archivo
chown -R usuario:grupo carpeta 

chmod 777 archivo.txt
```

Asigna todos los permisos al archivo `archivo.txt`

```
chmod 666
```

Asigna permisos de lectura y escritura, no de ejecución a todos los archivos y directorios del directorio donde ejecutamos el comando.

```
chmod -R 644
```

Esto da permisos a todos los archivos y directorios del directorio donde se invoca el comando y de todos los directorios que cuelgan de él. Los permisos asignados son de lectura a todos los usuarios, de escritura sólo al dueño del archivo y de ejecución a nadie.

Comment: Es mas facil decir que el flag -R funciona recursivamente. Ese es el tétmino correcto. Saludos

Comment: Buen aporte estimado =). Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

`chown` - cambia el usuario y grupo propietarios de ficheros

`chmod` - cambia los permisos de acceso de ficheros

Si quieres modificar los permisos sobre cierto grupo o cierto usuario, puedes utilizar `chmod` dando los permisos correspondientes.

Ahora en el caso de que los permisos estén correctamente asignados por ejemplo, pero decides que el directorio o archivo no pertenecen mas a cierto usuario o grupo lo haces cambiándolo mediante `chown`

Answer (score 3):

Fácil.

**chmod** te permite cambiar permisos de escritura, lectura y ejecución de un archivo o directorio. Mientras que **chown** te permite cambiar el dueño del archivo o directorio.

**Ejemplos para chmod:**

Dar todos los permisos al archivo.

```
$ chmod 777 miarchivo.txt
```

Dar permisos de ejecución

```
$ chmod +x miarchivo.txt
```

Quitar permisos de lectura y escritura al grupo

```
$ chmod g-r-w miarchivo.txt
```

**Ejemplos para chown:**

Cambiar de dueño

```
$ chown root miarchivo.txt
```

Cambiar al dueño user en el grupo developers

```
$ chown user:developers miarchivo
```